# Old movie similar to Clash of Titans (1981) but with Romans

Tags: story-identification, movie, mythology

Looking for this old movie with stop-motion effects. I have seen it TV in early 2000's in Czech dub, original language probably being English.

I remember only isolated scenes from the movie, but now after the years I'm intrigued by the idea of blending of Roman style intrigue and ancient mythology in one piece.

The scenes I remember (not chronologically):

- Character were fighting a dragon. It looked like a dinosaur with long neck and were wearing something like a collar. I believe they needed to sic another creature on it in order to defeat it.
- There was at least one siege scene. The walls were tall but looked like they were built from unfired clay.
- There is one scene where group of men are discussing the assassination of paranoid general (or even emperor) in a military camp or fort. The murder was to happen by the means of poisoned apple. Blind friend to the general was to be recruited for the act, he would be given a knife with blade poisoned only on one side to cut an apple with. Point being only blind person could tell which side of a knife is poisoned by touch and thereby which half of an apple is safe to eat.
- There was a rather lengthy duel between the Roman leader and a guy in "Atlantean" looking armor. I think the motivation for duel was retaking of fallen legionary standard, the duel ended in a draw, but Atlantean guy was so impressed by Romans swordsmanship that he let him take the standard back anyway.

Visual effects were stop-motion similar to those in the old  Clash of Titans, so I wanted to base my estimation of its age on that, but looking on how outdated those effects are, the movie I am looking for may have be made anywhen between 60's and 80's, but visuals were somewhat similar, only instead of Greek visuals Roman were used.

Comment: Not sure I'd fancy finding out which edge of a blade is poisoned "by feel"....

Answer (score 16):

It could be [***GOLIATH AND THE DRAGON (1960)***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054437/)

Plot

> A warrior returning home to his country must battle giant bats,
> three-headed dogs and a vicious dragon to save his wife, and his
> people, from the machinations of an evil ruler.

[**Full movie**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exYPYX_ZBws)

The Dragon:
[image]

Romans:
[image]

Siege scene?
[image]

The walls:
[image]

And there are some talks about poisoning and poison itself:
[image]

Comment: Your answsr looks a closer match than mine 

Comment: @JudithJones could be we have several movies mixed together ;)

Answer (score 7):

On the off-chance that you're conflating scenes from two different films, the first bullet point in your description could be a scene from near the end of ***[The 7th Voyage of Sinbad](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051337/)*** (1958) where a dragon fights a cyclops. The scene features stop motion animation and the dragon has a collar around its neck because it was initially chained to a wall. This film doesn't match the other bullet points in your description, though.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_7th_Voyage_of_Sinbad):

> **Sinbad awakens and rubs the magic lamp, summoning Barani, who takes Sinbad to Sokurah's fortress and helps him evade the chained dragon that stands guard.** Sinbad reaches Sokurah, who restores the princess to normal. When Sinbad refuses to hand over the lamp, the magician animates a skeleton warrior, which Sinbad fights and destroys. With the help of the genie, Sinbad and Parisa make their way out of the cave, stopping to destroy the lamp by throwing it into a pool of lava, thus freeing Barani.
>
> **Leaving the cave, they encounter another cyclops. Sinbad releases the dragon, which fights and kills the creature. Sinbad and Parisa make their escape, but Sokurah orders the dragon to hunt them down. Sinbad heads to the beach, where his men have readied the giant crossbow, and they use it to kill the dragon.**

Answer (score 6):

I think it is The Fall of The Roman Empire.(1964)

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058085/plotsummary/

I found it on YouTube.

It has the blind man murdering the leader with a poisoned apple.

> Overhearing this, Cleander, a blind prophet loyal to Commodus, presents Marcus with a poisoned apple.

Here is the full summary from IMDB

> The death of Marcus Aurelius leads to a succession crisis, in which the deceased emperor's son, Commodus, demonstrates that he is unwilling to let anything undermine his claim to the Roman Empire.
> Intent on securing peace and prosperity throughout the mighty Roman Empire, the wise diplomat, Emperor Marcus Aurelius, calls together the local governors from all over the Empire, after conquering the Germanic tribes. With this in mind, Marcus has decided to turn over his crown and the much-coveted imperial throne to General Livius, instead of choosing his corrupt son and logical successor, Commodus. As a result, high treason and blind ambition lead to the death of Aurelius by poisoning, paving the way for a new era of oppression, endless machinations, and rapid decline. Now, as darkness prevails on the outskirts of the Empire where the Roman legions struggle to subdue the invading hordes, delusional Commodus declares himself a god, and no one is safe; not even Aurelius' daughter, Lucilla. Can anyone stop the fall of the Roman Empire?
> —Nick Riganas
> Action-packed look at the beginnings of the fall of the Roman Empire. Here is the glory, the greed and grandeur that was Rome. Here is the story of personal lust for power, and the shattering effects of that power's loss. Here is the tale of the plight of a people living on the brink of a political abyss.
> —filmfactsman
> Marcus Aurelius Antonius, philosopher-emperor of Rome, summons his empire's governors and princes to German war headquarters for a Pax Romanus. He confides to his daughter, Lucilla, that his adopted son, Livius, will succeed him instead of his more unstable heir, Commodus. Overhearing this, Cleander, a blind prophet loyal to Commodus, presents Marcus with a poisoned apple. After the funeral, Livius, who does not share Lucilla's ambition for himself or Rome, allows Commodus to proclaim himself emperor. Lucilla marries Sohamus of Armenia. While pestilence ravages Rome, Commodus continues his vain, licentious behavior, neglecting all symptoms of unrest while banishing anyone reminding him of his responsibilities: Livius, Lucilla, Timonides the Greek

The Wikipedia page describes the production design,it sounds like quite a huge undertaking.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fall_of_the_Roman_Empire_(film)

> Production design

> A statue of Juno as seen in the movie, displayed at the Cinecittà studios in Rome, Italy
> Veniero Colasanti and John Moore served as the art directors overseeing the production design with the guidance of Will Durant. Actual construction began on October 1, 1962, using 1,100 men who labored for seven months. About 400 art students and craftsmen throughout Spain worked on the statuary, tiles, frescoes, and details of the set. The film's reconstruction of the Roman Forum was constructed in Las Matas near Madrid, approximately sixteen miles from Bronston's studio. The entire set was measured at 400 x 230 metres (1312 x 754 feet), which holds the record for the largest outdoor film set. Uniquely for the film, the set was not extended through the use of matte paintings.[12]

> The Temple of Jupiter was constructed on a 29-metre (95 ft) high hill along the plains of Las Matas by which craftsmen built the 50-metre (160 ft) temple on it. The bronze equestrian figures at the top of the temple were 24 metres (79 ft) above the pavement of the forum set. For the statuary, 350 statues had to be constructed. There were 76 life-size statues, more than a thousand sculpted bases for the remaining figures and victory columns, and a series of the aforementioned equestrian statues that were 7.6 metres (25 ft) high. Ultimately, more than 3,000 sketches were drawn to illustrate the 27 structures that would comprise the sets.[33] The various ancient Rome settings covered 22 hectares (54 acres).[34] After much of the set was pulled down, the remaining sections were reused in A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to the Forum (1966).

Comment: Is there a one-side-poisoned knife or a dragon?

Comment: I am watching the movie to find out. They are not mentioned in the summary.

Comment: Seems to be  "epic historical drama film", not sci fi or fantasy.